# How do I make this service call work in Angular 2

Tags: angular, http

I am trying to do all the http call in a base service class and just call the simple function from other services.

Base service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class Base1Service {
constructor(private http: Http) {};

url = 'someUrl';

httpGet(uriContext: string, options?: any) {
  return this.http.get(this.url + uriContext, options)
      .timeout(something)
      .map(something)
      .catch(something);
}

httpPost(uriContext: string, request?: any, options?: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + uriContext, request, options)
      .timeout(something)
      .map(something)
      .catch(something);
}

}
```

Other Service

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Base1Service} from './base1.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Headers, Http, RequestOptions, Response, Request, RequestMethod} 
from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class OtherService extends Base1Service {
// constructor(private http: Http) {
//   super(http);
// }

getTheData(): Observable<any> {
   const uriContext = 'something';
   const param = {
      'something': something
   };
   const headers = new Headers({
      'X-locale': something,
      'Authorization': something
   });
   const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
   return this.httpGet(uriContext, param, options);
}
```

It is not working for me, Am I missing out on something ?
If I put Constructor with a super() call, it says supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
Can you please help. I am new to Angular.

Comment: What are you trying to do?? What is the error?

Comment: Did you try to call your constructor in this way: contructor(private http: Http) { super(this.http); } ?

Comment: Please, use HttpClient, not the old http (with http you must use map, json, etc). see the documentation https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @Talavera yes, I tried now.say the service incorrectly extends the base service. Types have separate declarations of a private property 'http'.

Comment: @Eliseo, that does not help my case. but yes thanks,.. thats a good suggestion.

Comment: change private http: Http to protected http: Http in both services

Comment: @vegazz Please add this comment as the answer.. I would Like to upvote it.. Thanks for the solution. Also please explain why protected made it work. I am missing out on some basic understandings I guess

Comment: @Eliseo There's no HttpClient in Angular 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override a private class member in TypeScript.

So you need to change `private http: Http` to `protected http: Http` in both services

Answer (score 0):

Simply Replace Other Service with following code

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Base1Service} from './base1.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Headers, Http, RequestOptions, Response, Request, RequestMethod} 
from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class OtherService {
 constructor(private _base1Service: Base1Service) {

}

getTheData(): Observable<any> {
   const uriContext = 'something';
   const param = {
      'something': something
   };
   const headers = new Headers({
      'X-locale': something,
      'Authorization': something
   });
   const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
   return this._base1Service.(uriContext, param, options);
}
```